# Scoring depth for cutting drywall

Tags: drywall

new DIY’er here. I started on my first project to finish the walls of my garage(2 side walls). I hope I can pull this off(half way thru so yay).

Okay so here is my question:

I have got a 4x8 drywall that I need to cut to make 2 4x4 pieces and I took a utility knife and made a score, but when I try to snap it, it doesn’t. This is my first time cutting a drywall. So I am not sure if I am not applying enough pressure, or did not score it deep enough or something else. I watched so many youtube videos on this and no where on one talks about the depth of scoring, so I am assuming I am not doing something right(my position, drywall position, enough pressure etc.)

One last thing I can possible try is put the board face down, put one foot on one side and lift up the other side to snap it, can I do that or will I damage the drywall.

Comment: you have to score through the paper on one side.  should snap quite easily.  usually you score it while it is flat then bring the board vertical and knee it on the non scored side.  this 1/2" drywall ?

Comment: Have a fresh blade in... it's going to cut the paper more cleanly. Score once nice and straight and cut the paper. Score again, pressing harder following your original line. (Twice if 5/8ths.) Then you should be able to snap it. Then cut the paper on the back. It's handy to have a Stanley Surform or equivalent to square up the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also helps if you can put a straight edge such as a 2x4 under the drywall along the edge you want to break along. Scoring plus the straight else is usually sufficient to get a nice break without too much force.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Draw your line on the paper side - for normal drywall this is the white side.

### Step 2

Take utility knife and carefully go over line with a little pressure.   After doing this you should see your line easily.

### Step 3

Go over same line with a decent amount of pressure.   You should probably be getting about 1/8" deep.

### Step 4

Drywall sheets come normally in 4' by 8' (the 8' can go to 16') x two sheets taped together.   The 4' sides are left without protection, the longer sides are capped.   If your line goes through a capped side you want to dig into the line for a good 1/2-1" so you are basically halfway through it.   If you don't deeply score the edges, they can break.

### Step 5

Bend the drywall toward the paper side at your line.   You should not have to apply a lot of pressure and the "white" side should be inside the drywall sammich.

### Step 6

While the drywall is bent - I like it right at 90 degrees - score the non-paper side (the brown side) to finish the cut.   This should be 100% cut through as trying to tear part of it can pull some gypsum off the good side.

Comment: Step 5 seems backwards? The cut face is normally opened, so that would be brown in the middle of the "sandwich" (if you were going to 180, but like you, I normally stop at 90 and cut the brown then.